# Corona SDK: IAP Auto renewable

Tags: coronasdk, in-app-purchase

Is Auto-Renewable-In-App Purchases supported in Corona SDK?

I cannot find it at http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/monetization/IAP/index.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is beyond Corona SDK.

Corona only provides an API to do the transaction and purchase. Whether the subscription is auto renewing or not is not Corona's concern.